# Is there a way for JMeter to keep a log of the last 500 requests and responses sent?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

When you run JMeter in GUI mode and add a listener, you get a view of each request and response. This is lost when using non-GUI mode and instead you get a different output that instead summarizes the number of requests being sent and what percent of them passed/failed:

[image]

This is good, however I would also like to get a log of the requests and responses, since that is useful debugging info for the software I'm testing. There must be a simple way to do this?

Also, I plan on running these tests for relatively long durations (e.g. up 3 days, since they are stability tests) and I don't necessarily need all the request/response info. Is it possible to store, say, the last 500 requests/responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure JMeter to save request/response data in the .jtl results file by manipulating [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), example setup:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

Alternatively you can add a listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) and choose what, when and where to store.

"Simple" configuration option to save last X requests/responses is not available, if the above solution doesn't fit your needs you can consider implementing your own i.e. [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) connected with [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) so you will store request and response data into separate 500 files which will be overwritten when the counter resets